# order dotplot x-axis along diagonal line

Tags: r, seurat

I produced this dotplot using Seurat, as shown in the picture
[image]

but I would to order the plot to show the dots starting from bottom left to top right.
I could do this manually with
`my_levels <- c(names, names, names,..........)  Idents(obj_name) <- factor(Idents(obj_name), levels= my_levels)`
but I would to find a faster way to do it.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this answer is a little late. But If I understood the question correctly you could just order the list of genes differently to obtain the desired outcome.